# Replace Sentence with phrase or particular word?

Tags: word-request, phrases

I have following sentence,

```
"This morning the sun was shining"
```

What can possible replacement.

I tried

**In a fine morning**

**In clear morning**

but both of these doesn't look suitable.

Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Probably, *In a sunshine morning, ...* is what you're looking for.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I would say that that's ungrammatical.

Comment: @jimsug I agree. It's quite likely so. I felt that my phrase was "too contrived", but I was surprised that I found both "a sunshine morning" and "in a sunshine morning" on Google Books. I suspect that it might be an outdated phrase. Not sure, though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I can't find any on [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+sunshine+morning&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=31967607), [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=31967599), or [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31967597), I'm afraid. Where did you find it on Google Books?

Comment: @jimsug Here are some examples, http://books.google.com/books?id=ggoAAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA254&dq="In+a+sunshine+morning", http://books.google.com/books?id=NSgJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA88&dq="In+a+sunshine+morning", http://books.google.com/books?id=sfMRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA215&dq="a+sunshine+morning", http://books.google.com/books?id=BqQlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA37&dq="a+sunshine+morning", http://books.google.com/books?id=W0jyXoo3Dz8C&pg=PA561&dq="a+sunshine+morning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *A sunny morning* can be used to replace your sentence.

Comment: but here sunny morning doesn't represent a hot day or hot morning.

It is fine weather, not hot day.

Comment: Both "sunny morning" and "the sun was shining" don't necessarily mean the day was hot.